# Java Internet Speed Test

Tags: java, networking

> Hello friends,
>
> I am trying to verify the internet speed through the sample java code.
> But when I compare the same with the website let say fast.com the
> results are very different. Can you help me to understand if I am
> missing anything?

```
 public static void testSpeed() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
            
            long totalDownload = 0; // total bytes downloaded
            final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024; // size of the buffer
            byte[] data = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE]; // buffer
            int dataRead = 0; // data read in each try
            long startTime = System.nanoTime(); // starting time of download
            BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(
                    new URL(
                            "https://www.google.com/")
                            .openStream());
            while ((dataRead = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) > 0) {
                totalDownload += dataRead; // adding data downloaded to total data
            }
            double downloadTime=(System.nanoTime() - startTime);
            /* download rate in bytes per second */
            double bytesPerSec = totalDownload
                    / ((downloadTime)  / 1000000000 );
            System.out.println(bytesPerSec + " Bps");
            /* download rate in kilobytes per second */
            double kbPerSec = bytesPerSec / (1024);
            System.out.println(kbPerSec + " KBps ");
            /* download rate in megabytes per second */
            double mbPerSec = kbPerSec / (1024);
            System.out.println(mbPerSec + " MBps ");
        
        }
```

> The results i am getting as :
> 66785.29693193253 Bps
> 65.22001653509037 KBps
> 0.06369142239754919 MBps

Results from fast.com is : 140 MBPS

Comment: java adds the JVM layer between the system and your program- this causes the program some latency and can make commands not execute as fast as possible. to implement this program I would have used C to be as fast as possible or use some API that someone else already made for you or JNI library that you will make. but I fear making it directly in Java is not a reliable way

Comment: You would need to read more than the Google home page to get a closer to accurate measurement.